# Why is this number type ? (TypeScript)

Tags: typescript

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4] as const;
type Arr = typeof arr[number];
// expected & result type : 1 | 2 | 3 | 4

const doubledArr = arr.map(el => el * 2);
type DoubledArr = typeof doubledArr[number];
// expected type : 2 | 4 | 6 | 8
// result type : number
```

I expected DoubledArr type as 2 | 4 | 6 | 8 by arr.
But the DoubleArr type came out as the number.
How can I get the DoubledArr type as 2 | 4 | 6 | 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sort of a mathematical transformation isn't something typescript can figure out statically. If you want that to be the resulting type, you will need to assert it:

```
const doubledArr = arr.map((el) => el * 2 as 2 | 4 | 6 | 8 );
// OR:
const doubledArr = arr.map((el) => el * 2) as (2 | 4 | 6 | 8)[];
```

Keep in mind that type assertions are basically a way to tell typescript "i know better then you, so don't check my work here". If you make a mistake with the assertion, typescript won't be able to warn you about it (unless it's an extremely obvious mistake)

If [this feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26382) ever got implemented it might include those capabilities, but i wouldn't expect that any time soon.

Comment: I have a question. So, Can't I inferred without using as?
If I use as wrong, DoubleArr type become wrong type.

ex) const doubledArr = arr.map((el) => el * 2 as 8 | 8 | 8 | 8 );

Comment: I don't know of any way to do this without a type assertion (ie, `as`). And yes, if you use it wrong, it will be wrong. Typescript will trust you and will not verify that you did it right.